# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "IosAwnCore"

Tags: flutter

Question:

When trying to run "pod update" in my flutter project, I encountered an error related to the "IosAwnCore" pod. The error message reads: "CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod 'IosAwnCore'". How can I resolve this issue?

#### Link to related question:

[image]